# Не вижу ошибку в коде

Tags: python, python-3.x

Где ошибка? Я не понимаю.

```
def b(strng):
    sym=' ,.-?!";:)('
    num='0123456789Z'
    strong=strng
    for i in range(11):
        strong=strong.replace(sym(i),num(i))
    answer=sum(seq1[strong[i]]*62**i for i in range(len(strong)))*2
    answer=''.join(seq2[answer//(62**i)%62] for i in range(int((log(answer)/log(62)))+1))
    return answer
```

Вот сама ошибка:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/maxwell/pseudo.py", line 62, in <module>
>   print(b('Cipher'))
> File "/home/maxwell/pseudo.py", line 49, in b
>   strong=strong.replace(sym(i),num(i))
> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Если после имени объекта используются круглые скобки, то Python воспринимает это как вызов функции:

```
sym(i)
```

и

```
num(i)
```

являются строками - отсюда ошибка: `'str' object is not callable`

Используйте квадратные скобки для индексирования строк:

```
strong = strong.replace(sym[i], num[i])
```

Comment: О, черт. Как я мог не заметить. Спасибо, сейчас исправлю

Comment: В дополнение к ответу добавлю: у вас в выводе ошибки так и написано - `'str' object is not callable`. Переводится как `Объект 'str' (string) не может быть вызван`. Понимание того, что написано в ошибке - львиная доля понимания программирования в дальнейшем. Учитесь понимать эти логи. Если разобраться, там всё предельно понятно. Чуть ли не носом разработчика тыкают в место, где есть ошибка.